# What is the voltage divider rule?

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, basic, biasing

Can anyone explain what the voltage divider rule is? How has the author of [this book](http://ubuntuone.com/2Yve9HztGuD7VBNyWVHXUe) used it for analyzing the Voltage Divider Bias circuit for transistors?

And can anyone explain how the two resistors are parallel? And how has the author assumed the battery to be a short circuit (as shown in Figure 4.28)?

Thanks a lot.

________________________________---

From above link:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There IS NO "voltage divider rule" as such. Even if somebody used that term there is still no such rule. BECAUSE the terminology is much too general. That's even more general than saying eg "The Ohm's law rule" where you at least have some guide. | If you have a specific question you should explain it clearly in words and not use general terms or few rods. | It **MAY** be of assistance to you to note that equation 4.29 in the above cited text COULD be called "the voltage divider rule" as it refers to R1, R2 and Vcc.

Comment: this video explains how voltage dividers work, i recommend you check it out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxLKfAZrhbM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) It **MAY** be of assistance to you to note that equation 4.29 in the above cited text COULD be called "the voltage divider rule" as it refers to R1, R2 and Vcc. ie changing what it says just slightly without changing the meaning:

- Vout = Vin x R2 / (R1 + R2)

ie R1 & R2 form a voltage divider and the above equation defines a "rule" of the result.

BUT

(2) **There IS NO "voltage divider rule" as such.**

Even if somebody uses that term there is still no such rule.
 BECAUSE the terminology is much too general.
 That's even more general than saying eg "The Ohm's law rule"
 where you at least have some guide.

If you have a specific question you should explain it clearly in words and not use general terms or few words or the real requirement is liable to be missed.

### Added:

Re question:

- Can you tell me how this 'rule' is derived? I'm a beginner so I didn't understand how he got the relation Vr2= (R2)(Vcc)/(R1+R2)

(1) Short answer.
 Voltage across each resistor is proportional to current in it (Ohm's law).

As current in both resistors
 = battery current
 = the same
 THEN the voltages across each resistor are proportional to their resistance value.
 **THIS IS THE KEY FACTOR THAT MAKES THIS WORK**

Vout = Vr2 = ib x R2
 Vcc = Vr1+Vr2 = ib x R1 + ib x R2 = ib x (R1 + R2)

So Vout / Vcc
 = Vr2 / (Vr1 + VR2)
 = ib x R2 / (ib x (R1 + R2)     )
 Cancel ib's
 Vout/Vcc= R2/(R1 + R2)
 Multiply both sides by Vcc.
 Vout = Vcc x R2 / (R1 + R2)
 QED.

(2) Longer answer.

You **MUST** know Ohms law.
If you don't know Ohms law and it's various re arrangements, stop reading this now, drop all lse and learn it. Wikipedia and Google know all about it N time over

... time lapse ... or no time at all as the case may be ...
 So we know you know Ohm's law.

So - one version of Ohm's law says, as you know

- V = i x R

ie the voltage drop across a resistor is equal to the value of the resistor multiplied by the current flowing in it.

Now look at fig 4-29

[image]

Take this circuit in isolation.
 The current from the battery flows from B+ at the top left of R1, via R1, then via R2 and back to B- and the bottom left. 
 Look at the diagram and be SURE that you agree with the above.
 Now, lets call the battery current Ib.

Call the current in R1 I_R1.
 It can be seen "by inspection that I_R1 = Ib.

Call the current in R2 I_R2.
 It can be seen "by inspection that I_R2 = Ib.

So I_R1 = IR2 = Ib.
 ie the current is the same in each resistor and out of and into the battery.

Now, the voltage across R1 = VR1 is, based on Ohm's law = I_R1 x R1.
 And, the voltage across R2 = VR2 is, based on Ohm's law = I_R2 x R2.

BUT I_R1 = Ib and IR2 = Ib.

So  VR1 = I_R1 x R1 = Ib x R1
 And VR2 = I_R2 x R2 = Ib x R2

The ratio of VR2 / VR1 = Ib x R2 / Ib x R1 = R2/R1
 ie the voltages across the two resistors are proportional to their resistance values.

Look at the diagram.
 Vbattery = Vcc
 Vcc = the voltage across R1 + the Voltage across R2
 Vcc = VR1 + VR2
 Vcc = ib x R1  + ib x R2
 Vcc = ib (R1 + R2)

So
To determine the ratio Vout / Vcc:

Vout / Vcc  = V_R2 / Vcc
 = ib x R2 / ib (R1 + R2)
 but the ib's cancel so
 Vout/ Vcc = R2 / (R1 + R2)
 and rearranging

Vout = Vcc x R2 / (R1 + R2)

So the voltage across R2 compared to battery voltage = Vr2= (R2)(Vcc)/(R1+R2)

Comment: Can you tell me how this 'rule' is derived? I'm a beginner so I didn't understand how he got the relation Vr2= (R2)(Vcc)/(R1+R2)

Comment: And please explain how he obtained Eq 4.28 by considering the *source as a short circuit*.. Is that permitted?

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the trouble to answer. I copied the text from the edited question to your previous answer so that it'll help other users.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've understood the whole working except for the initial 2 steps: 
`It can be seen "by inspection that I_R1 = Ib` and 
`It can be seen "by inspection that I_R2 = Ib`
How can the current through *both* the resistors be equal to the base current Ib? Forgive me if I sound stupid, I really don't get it.
And I *assure* you that I **have** learnt Ohm's law. Again, thanks for answering.

Comment: @russellMcMahon, an edit was suggested to add further content to your answer. It seemed to be an improvement adding greater value, so I approved the edit. I wanted to notify you so you could look over the information that your answer now contains and make sure it meets your quality guidlines or if it needs some tweaking.

Comment: @GreenNoob -  I said "take this circuit in isolation" and, Ib = Ibattery.  Note that Ib <> Ibase (doesn't = Ibase) in this case.  ie in this case there IS NO Ibase - as we are looking at the isolated circuit. Later on when you combine them you MAY perturb the result by drawing base current. If/when you do, Ohm's law still applies an you can work out the new result, eg base current will increase Ir1 so Vr1 will increase so Vr2 will drop and Ir2 will thus drop. ||Thevenin shows it all cancels out in the end. Thevenin's an annoying but essential man to know - just common sense written as a law.

Comment: @Kortuk - Thanks. head spins. Looks OK :-). Thanks for subtly & indirecty noting I may be prickly. Must devise a new year's resolution re being less prickly :-) :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, many many users can take offense at someone changing what they said and it still showing their name. I think it would be nice to be notified when something you have written is edited so I attempt to give such a notice on any large edits I approve or conduct. In this case it was a long enough edit that I also wanted to pass the buck on reviewing technical accuracy :)

Comment: @Kortuk - I wasn't complaining - just noting nice polite way it was brought to my attention :-). I'm a bit lost with what I wrote where (it having been middle of night throughout with work happening in paralleland all that) - I see the material is what I wrote or posted by what was where is now unclear. It all looks fine though - thanks.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, everything after and including the large "Added" was edited in. You wrote everything previous. It is hard to tell when you click on the edited because there is a dotted line that you must click to show text that was unchanged by the edit.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yes. Hence my confusion. I wrote the material after "Added" but I'm not sure where it was added from :-). Presumably / apparently I may have posted it in his question when I probably intended to add it at the top of my answer and he has taken it from where I put it by mistake and put it near but nor exactly where I had intended it to go - hence my confusion. Perils of rushing to and fro in the night watches :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, yes, point taken, that is confusing, it did look like your writing.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks a lot.. I've got it at last..

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Just one more question.. What's the use of Equation 4.28???

Comment: In fig 4:30 the RESISTOR used is calculated in 4.28 and the VOLTAGE used is calculated from fig 4:29. These are the Thevenin resistance and Thevenin voltage of the source. Thevenin is saying that two R's and a voltage source look identical to this lower voltage and different single  R value.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sorry, I promised that I'd ask only one question, but I can't stop myself. While determining the Thevenin voltage, we take the circuit (fig 4.29) in *isolation* but why don't we do that while determining the equivalent resistance? Aren't the resistors in *series* when considered in isolation rather than parallel as implied by Eq 4.28?

Comment: @GreenNoob - In isolation means "all relevant parts" in isolation. In 4.29 the battery is included as a voltage source because you are interested in voltages. In 4.28 the voltage source is included as a resistance as here we are interested in resistances. AND the impedance or resistance of an ideal volage source = 0 ohms. So it is shown as a short, as it acts as if it is shorted to ground. | You haven't taken Olin's advice (and mine) yet and looked up Thevenin, hav you ? :-). This is EXACTLY what Thevenin deals with. If you'd done your "homework" you'd have known the answer :-). X

Comment: mORE QUESTIONS WELCOME. but, DO DO YOUR HOMEWORK.

Answer (score 4):

We are looking at an AC amplifier.

The DC part of the amplifier is only about setting up the Q-Point, or Working Point of the transistor.

Once that is determined, the actual AC workings can be looked at.

I would propose you get hold of a complete book on basic electronics. The text you showed us here expects quite a bit of knowledge in the reader.

But lets see how this works out:

- Fig. 4.25: We describe the circuit.
- Fig. 4.27: The step showing the DC Part of the input side
- Fig. 4.28: What remains if we look at AC -> VCC is replaced with a shortcut. This is a way to calculate the internal resistance of the network we are looking at. This is only a hypothetical step in a mathematical technique.
- "Applying the Voltage Divider Rule", meaning no other thing than "seeing how in 4.28 the Resistances are in parallel, we calculate the parallel resistance using the well known formula. But lets call it a rule".
- This all happens expecting the reader knows how to apply the Thevenin Theorem, which doubtlessly was explained earlier in the book.
- Fig. 4.29 Lets draw the resulting Network, showing the black box we are transforming.
- Eq 4.30 Calculating Ib using the Theremin replacement, this also happens in DC.
- Fig. 4.30 Two steps in this one: First, 4.29 is replaced by the appropriate Thevenin replacement. Secondly, it is applied to the base of the transistor.
- Equation 4.31 has very little to do with the whole path so far, it is simply the summation of the voltages on the output side.

In fact, Msr. Thevenin was a French pioneer of electronics, read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem). He was not at all mentioned in my studies as an electrical engineer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the [book I'm referring to](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Electronic_Devices_and_Circuit_Theory.html?id=VXIpwBYOjcgC&redir_esc=y) does not mention Thevenin's theorem anywhere before this section.

Comment: & upvote for the link to the Wikipedia article. It helped.

Comment: "He was not at all mentioned in my studies as an electrical engineer. " -- really?

Comment: fyi, I just wrote a blog article last week on Thevenin equivalents: http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/115.php

Comment: @posipiet: If you've never heard of Thevenin equivalent circuits, then you really should look it up and read about it.  While you're at it, do the same for Norton equivalent circuits.  The two are complementary.

Comment: @JasonS, I enjoyed your article a lot. I read a few others and I enjoyed [the article on 10 components you should know](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/112.php) quite a bit also.

Comment: While visiting Mr Thevenin, be sure to call on Mt Kirchoff. [Kirchoff's circuit laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws).  - Wikipedia

Comment: @Olin: Of course both equivalencies were tought to us, including their limitations, but names were not given.

Answer (score -1):

### Voltage divider

The "voltage divider rule" can be directly seen in a geometrical way by means of a *voltage diagram* - Fig. 1. I have explained in detail this visualization technique in [my Codidact paper](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/284873); here I will only briefly show its idea.

[image: Voltage divider visualized]

Fig. 1. Voltage diagram of a potentiometer (from [my Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Walking_along_the_Resistive_Film) about Ohm's law)

The discrete voltage divider R1-R2 is replaced by a linear potentiometer with two partial resistances *r1* and *r2*. The local voltages along them are represented by vertical segments (*voltage bars*) in red with proportional height.

Since the voltage linearly decreases when moving from the left to right from the maximum V to zero, the height of the voltage bars also linearly decreases… and their envelope is a triangle.

Actually, we can see two nested right triangles with legs V, r1 + r2 for the big (external) triangle and Vout, r2 for the small (internal) triangle.

It is seen from the similarity that V/Vout = (r1 + r2)/r2.

### Voltage summer

The same can be done with the "resistor summer rule" (widely used in op-amp inverting circuits) - Fig. 2.

[image: Passive resistor summer visualized]

Fig. 2. Voltage diagram of a
resistor voltage summer (from [my Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Walking_along_the_Resistive_Film))

Here the similar right triangles are opposite (external) with legs Vin1,r1 for the left triangle and Vin2,r2 for the right triangle.

It is seen from the similarity that Vin2/Vin1 = -r2/r1.